# How to use the function transaction.retrieve() to get receipt data?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am developing a transaction workflow capsule, and I use the function transaction.retrieve() to get order data from the platform. But it returns **only part of the order data**.

MyReceipt is a structure stored the order informations, it is defined like this:

```
structure (MyReceipt) {
  description (order info)

  // properties

  features { activity}
}
```

And it is built as a output concept of Commit Action, like this

```
action (CommitRequest) {
  type (Commit)
  description ()
  collect {
   // MyRequest
  }
  output (MyReceipt)
}
```

I try to get data like this

```
transaction.retrieve("bixby.MyCapsule.MyReceipt")
```

It is supposed to return all the MyReceipt Data. But it return only part of the Receipt data.Is it right to get all the orders? Or is there other ways to get all the receipt data?

And I have found the sample code use it just like this to get the last Receipt data

```
transaction.retrieve("bixby.MyCapsule.MyReceipt", "ALL", 1)
```

but it doesn't explain what **these two parameter "ALL" and 1 represent for**. And I want to get more details about the usage of this function.

Could you plz tell me **how to use the function transaction.retrieve() or other function to get all the Receipt historical data**, and How can I check out **the transaction data for someone** when I try to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: First I would like to apologize for not able to answer sooner, we are working on an answer on the argument documentation, but not as easy as I originally thought. Meanwhile, can you use the "Contact Support" under "Help" menu in Bixby IDE to give us some detail about what utterance and what result you expect, and what part of the result you did not get.

Comment: The documentation can be found here: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/transaction

Not sure why a moderator deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the answer from dogethis. (Thanks, man! You do the hard work, I took credit)

We have the DOC ready online [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/transaction)

Basically, **ALL** is the default to get all state of transaction data, and **1** means only one record. The API page was not there before, so thanks for let us know.

I think it's the **1** cause you not get all record, but it does has a limit 20...

Have fun with Bixby!

Comment: **Thank you for you answer**, and Is there some way to get **all receipt data** so that I can show the all historical orders?

Comment: I had tested it by setting the limit to 20 and it still return only one receipt object in IDE and preCN and preUS servers. And I can only get one receipt in the booking and purchasing column in manage tab in capsule info page. Does the platform only stores the latest receipt order?

Comment: You must set a unique $id for each object when you return it.

For example,

return {
   myObjectField: 'asdf',
   $id: 'a-unique-id'
}

(`$id` is not part of your model - it's an internal field and should not be modeled.)